# Only first media query is working which is above 851px but other media queries not working

Tags: html, css, angular

I am using this code to format my products page, but my media queries are not working.

Only the first query is working (which is above 851px)

My code:

```
.my-prods-container{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
    .my-prods{
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width:851px){
        .my-prods{
            flex-basis: 21%;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (min-width:601px)and(max-width:850px){
        .my-prods{
            flex-basis: 30%;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (min-width:401px)and(max-width:600px){
        .my-prods{
            flex-basis: 45%;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:400px){
        .my-prods{
            flex-basis: 90%;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ).  Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: "is not working" isn't a proper problem description. See that link I gave you, and add details such as error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your media queries are well crafted, but you need to add spaces between 
the `and`.

Like so:

```
@media screen and (min-width:601px) and (max-width:850px)
```